# Eval function expression

Tags: javascript, eval

While I was expecting that this code

```
var  a = eval("function() { return 1; }");

console.log(a());
```

prints '1' in the console, I get a syntax error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`. What am I doing wrong here?

---

I am working with a framework that allows to define javascript functions in the configuration, so I have no other choice but using eval.

Comment: It's...invalid code. Open a file and add a line `function() { return 1; }` then execute it - you'd get the same result

Comment: function *declarations* must give a name to the function. As opposed to function *expressions* which can be - and often are - anonymous

Comment: You have to give the function a name. `eval("function a() { return 1; }"); console.log(a());` would work and so does `eval("var a = function() { return 1; }");
console.log( a() );`, but you can't combine the two approaches to write a function this way. PS: Do not use `eval()` unless you know exactly why it's the only option to use.

Comment: @shilly make an answer out of it an I can mark it as solved

Comment: Then use `new Function( 'return 1;' );` instead of `eval()`. The result is the same, but it's slightly less insecure.

Comment: @Shilly no, having the function a name doesn't mean you can then execute it by doing `a()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix function declaration and function expressions this way. You have to do the full declaration or expression inside the `eval()`.

```js
 eval("function a() { return 1; }");
 console.log(a());
```

This would work, as we give the function declaration a proper name, `a`, and then call the function this creates on the global scope.

```js
 eval("var a = function() { return 1; }");
 console.log( a() );
```

This would also work, since the function expression assigning it to the variable `a` is now part of what gets evaluated. And we can then call the function in it's scope.

Neither of these should actually ever be used if there's alternatives.
The most common alternative is using `new Function();`.

```js
var a = new Function( 'return 1;' );
console.log( a() );
```

This achieves the same end result and is slightly safer than using `eval()`.

I would be surprised though if this was the only way the framework allows to define extra javascript functions. I guess that since it's in the config of something the security issues this gives are less important than if it's public code. But i would reread the docs of the framework to double check that this is the only option.

Answer (score 4):

The `function` keyword is ambiguous in Javascript: it can start a function declaration (a statement), or a function literal (an expression). When `function` is encountered in the statement position, the parser voluntarily prefers declaration over expression. Since `eval` expects a statement, this makes your code invalid -- function name is required for declarations. You can either provide a name:

```
eval('function foo() {...}')
```

or force the parser into the expression mode

```
foo = eval('( function () {...} )')
```

in which case `function` will be treated as a literal.

This is basically the same story as with `{}`, which can be either a block or an object literal. Something like `eval('{1:2}')` will fail for exactly the same reason (statement preferred over expression).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have a [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) and that requires a name. For reference, this is a function declaration

```js
function myFunc() { console.log("executed") } //<-- declaration

myFunc(); //<-- execution
```

What you *expect* to have is an unnamed function expression

```js
var myFunc = function() { console.log("executed") }
//expression ^------------------------------------^

myFunc(); //<-- execution
```

Or for a truly unnamed function that you do not assign to a variable, you can have an IIFE

```js
// v--------- brackets surrounding expression ---------v
   (            function() { console.log("executed") } )()
//expression    ^------------------------------------^  ^^
//execution  -------------------------------------------++
```

However, in JavaScript a standalone statement that starts with the `function` keyword will be treated as *declaration* and if it doesn't have a name, it is invalid.

However, you can go around that by surrounding the expression in brackets to make it acceptable for the parser.

```js
//brackets    v--------------------------v
var a = eval("( function() { return 1; } )");
//              ^----------------------^ function expression
console.log(a());
```

Answer (score 1):

As the comments are 100% true that a function must contain a name or has to be initialised as an anonymous function, there is a solution to your problem.

If you want to create a function by text you could use the function constructor

```
new Function ([arg1[, arg2[, ...argN]],] functionBody)
```

For more information look at https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function